# Compute squared difference of n equal length lists of an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to design a function that basically computes the squared difference for equal length lists based on the combinations of those lists by the formula [n(n-1)]/2:

So for my data:

```
arr = np.array([[10, 20, 30, 40],  #list_1
                [11, 12, 13, 14],  #list_2
                [22, 23, 25, 27],  #list_3
                [12, 19, 24, 78]]) #list_4
```

I want to be doing this:

```
final_arr = ((arr[0] - arr[1])**2 +
             (arr[0] - arr[2])**2 +
             (arr[0] - arr[3])**2 +
             (arr[1] - arr[2])**2 +
             (arr[1] - arr[3])**2 +
             (arr[2] - arr[3])**2)
```

Output:

```
list(final_arr) = [371, 260, 616, 9155]
```

As you can see it's basically all `6 ([(4*3)/2] = 6)` combinations of lists i.e.

```
[(list_1, list_2), (list_1, list_3), (list_1, list_4), (list_2, list_3), (list_2, list_4), (list_3, list_4)]
```

I'm trying to build a function that can do this for an array containing `n` amount of equal length lists.

Comment: In python, exponent is `**`

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated the question, I forgot to update from pseudo code.

Comment: @deadshot added the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip)

```
from itertools import combinations

lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4]
for x in zip(*lists):
    print(sum((c[0] - c[1]) ** 2 for c in combinations(x, 2)))
```

**Output:**

```
371
260
616
9155
```

Using [numpy.apply_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
fun = lambda x: sum((c[0] - c[1]) ** 2 for c in combinations(x, 2))
res = np.apply_along_axis(fun, 0, arr)
print(list(res))
```

**Output:**

```
[371, 260, 616, 9155]
```

Comment: this works exactly as expected, but upon working with it I realized that using an array of lists can take away the need of a for loop, I just wanted to ask if you could take a look at the question again.

Comment: even if you have array of lists you still need to find the combination of each row. so it's impossible without using for loop

Comment: true, I've been trying to do that. do you have any suggestion how that could be done with an array, as you can see in my updated version, I no longer require a for loop to compute the result.

Comment: answer accepted, this is awesome. The main reason I have it in array is because I sometime have say 12 lists in an array which is 66 pairs so this makes it way easier. Thank YOU!!!!!!